# mongo: /data/db not found on AWS ec2 t2.micro after launching an AMI image of the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, parse-server, bitnami

S.O.S!! I had my t2.micro with Bitnami Parse image running for a good while.

everything was fun and games until I needed to upgrade to t2.medium.

In order to do so I cloned my server to an AMI image. Then I launched my brand new t2.medium from my AMI image. I woke up in the morning just to discover that my old server is giving me the following error when I run the command `mongod`:

```
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
starting : pid=1696 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-37-229
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.9
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:
20d60d3491908f1ae252fe452300de3978a040c7
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info:
Linux build4.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 
21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-07-18T07:07:09.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-07-18T07:07:09.756+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in 
initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-07-18T07:07:09.756+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

First I thought there duplicated t2.medium server is causing issues so I terminated it. but still nothing changed on my old t2.micro. and I cannot locate my old mongodb data!!!!

My question is: is this a result due to a side affect that might have being caused due to the AMI image process or it's something else. perhaps an attack on my server!!!!!

I am in great trouble. Any help will be much appreciated!!!

T.I.A

Comment: To change the size of an instance you stop the instance, change the size, then start it again. When you say "cloned your server to an AMI image" did you create a snapshot, create an AMI from that snapshot, then start a new server - or did you do something else? Creating a snapshot / AMI does not alter the contents of your server / disk. Do you have snapshots you can restore from, or a backup of your database outside of AWS?

Comment: Hi Tim. inside my console I clicked on the top button "Actions" while my specific instance is clicked and in the dropdown menu there is a tab called "Image" which offers you to create an image in AMI's. and then I entered AMI's, located my new Image and launched a new instance from that.

Comment: That isn't a destructive process, it takes a snapshot then creates an AMI for you. Anything that's gone wrong is independent of that.